# Is it correct to use the word "imperative" to say that something should be the priority?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> In my view, prevention is more imperative than cure because treatment
> procedures are mostly intensive and expensive.

In this sentence I want to say that authorities and people should invest more on preventing diseases rather than trying to find cures for different illnesses. I do not want to say that prevention is more important than treatment. Absolutely it is very important to cure someone who is ill. But it is a wise decision if we improve public health measure and personal hygiene to decrease the diseases. Did I use the word **imperative** correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I do not believe this is the correct way to use imperative.
The primary definition on [google define](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20imperative) is;

> of vital importance; crucial.

Imperative gives an absolute level of importance, it is not used to define things in a relative way as in the example you provided. Imperative means it has to be done. It isn't usual to say this thing that has to be done, has to be done more than some other thing that has to be done.

The more common phrase that would be used here would be "Prevention is better than cure." Indeed a search for that phrase will turn up numerous [public](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/753688/Prevention_is_better_than_cure_5-11.pdf) [health](https://www.rcn.org.uk/get-involved/campaign-with-us/prevention-is-better-than-cure#:%7E:text=The%20phrase%20%27prevention%20is%20better,Desiderius%20Erasmus%20in%20around%201500.&text=See%3A%20King%27s%20Fund%20%2D%20Prevention%20is,where%20illness%20has%20not%20occurred.) articles making the same point you have.